# Loading infinitely nested tuples from YAML

Tags: python, nested, yaml, self-contained

The following code generates an infinitely nested python list:

```
import yaml
i_list = yaml.load('&id1 [3, *id1]')
print i_list
# [3, [...]]
print i_list[1] is i_list
# True
```

I can also explicitly mention the python `list` type:

```
i_list = yaml.load('&id1 !!python/list [3, *id1]')
```

And I can also manually create that structure without parsing yaml, as follows:

```
i_list = [3]
i_list.append(i_list)
```

However, the last trick won't work for tuples, or any other immutable object. To create an infinitely-nested tuple, I must use CPython's API:

```
from ctypes import pythonapi
from _ctypes import PyObj_FromPtr

t = pythonapi.PyTuple_New(1)
pythonapi.PyTuple_SetItem(t, 0, t)
i_tup = PyObj_FromPtr(t)
print repr(i_tup)
# ((...),)
```

The expected yaml code for such a tuple would look like that:

```
&id001 !!python/tuple
- *id001
```

and indeed, this is the output of `yaml.dump(i_tup)`. However, python's yaml can't load the very same code:

```
yaml.load(yaml.dump(i_tup))

ConstructorError: found unconstructable recursive node
  in "<string>", line 1, column 1:
    &id001 !!python/tuple
    ^
```

Any good reason why it is so? Any workaround you could suggest?

Comment: Why use infinite nesting?

Comment: Only playing around...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples are simply not designed to do this. There's no way to build such a thing through the ordinary Python API, and even the [C API](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/af1351800c7a/Objects/tupleobject.c#l135) that lets you get around it has a check (`op->ob_refcnt != 1`) that is very likely to break things if you try:

```
int
PyTuple_SetItem(register PyObject *op, register Py_ssize_t i, PyObject *newitem)
{
    register PyObject *olditem;
    register PyObject **p;
    if (!PyTuple_Check(op) || op->ob_refcnt != 1) {
        Py_XDECREF(newitem);
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return -1;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you try to set any items of a tuple with this function after putting in a self-reference, Python detects the self-reference as an error. Build tuples like this at your own risk, and don't be surprised if your code breaks for weird reasons.